# To add hh/mm/ss to date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query i want to add hh/mm/ss in date.I want to add 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 to my date .pls help me to do this.

```
@i_StartDate VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT Distinct p.ProductID,  
       p.ProductName,  
       ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL( CurrentStock,0.00)   
        FROM   Productstatus PS  
        WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID  
               AND PS.LocationID = 1  
               AND  PS.StatusDateTime>= @i_StartDate+'00:00:00' AND  PS.StatusDateTime<= @i_StartDate+'23:59:59'
               and PS.productid=p.productid),0) OpeningStockQuantity
     from Product p
```

Comment: Why not ````PS.StatusDateTime = @i_StartDate```` where ````@i_StartDate = '2014-11-01'```` ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Datetime should help you..

```
SELECT Distinct p.ProductID,  
       p.ProductName,  
       ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL( CurrentStock,0.00)   
        FROM   Productstatus PS  
        WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID  
               AND PS.LocationID = 1  
               AND  PS.StatusDateTime>= convert(datetime,@i_StartDate+' 00:00:00') AND  PS.StatusDateTime<= convert(datetime,@i_StartDate+' 23:59:59')
               and PS.productid=p.productid),0) OpeningStockQuantity
     from Product p
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Time in the Date and Cast to Datetime

```
SELECT Distinct p.ProductID,  
   p.ProductName,  
   ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL( CurrentStock,0.00)   
    FROM   Productstatus PS  
    WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID  
           AND PS.LocationID = 1  
           AND  
CAST(PS.StatusDateTime as DATETIME)>= 
CAST(DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,@i_StartDate), '00:00:00') as DATETIME) AND 
CAST(PS.StatusDateTime as DATETIME)<= 
CAST(DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,@i_StartDate), '23:59:59') as DATETIME) AND
PS.productid=p.productid),0) OpeningStockQuantity
 from Product p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND  PS.StatusDateTime>= CONCAT(@i_StartDate,' 00:00:00')

 AND 

 PS.StatusDateTime<= CONCAT(@i_StartDate,' 23:59:59')
```

-->

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on SQL 2008+ just cast the StatusDateTime as Date and compare to your @i_StartDate.

```
DECLARE @i_StartDate date = '2014-11-01'

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        p.ProductID,  
        p.ProductName,  
        ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CurrentStock,0.00)   
        FROM   Productstatus PS  
        WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID  
            AND PS.LocationID = 1  
            AND  CAST(PS.StatusDateTime AS DATE) = @i_StartDate
            AND PS.productid=p.productid),0) OpeningStockQuantity
        FROM Product p
```

Comment: The formats accepted will depend on your installation. What data type and format is the PS.StatusDateTime?